# How do I reset the content of an onsen ui dialog after I hide it?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

Right now I am using onsen ui dialog to open a form. This form gets data from a form on the page that opened it. After they fill out 1 field (the rest of the fields are pre filled with data from the form on the page that launched the dialog) they hit save. I then save the data. This all works fine, but if they repeat the process, the form in the dialog keeps the same data. I tried to do a `dialog.destroy()` but then the dialog never launches.

Here is the code I have before I added the `dialog.destroy()`

```
module.controller('AppController', function ($scope, $localStorage, $window) {
    $scope.dialogs = {};
    $scope.combos = $window.localStorage.getItem('combos') || [];

    $scope.saveCombo = function(dlg){
        var getComboName=$("#comboName").val();
        var getCombo1=$("#combo1").val();
        var getCombo2=$("#combo2").val();
        var getCombo3=$("#combo3").val();
        var thisCombo=[getComboName,getCombo1,getCombo2,getCombo3];

        $scope.combos.push({"name": getComboName, "combo1": getCombo1, "combo2": getCombo2, "combo3": getCombo3});
        $window.localStorage.setItem('combos', $scope.combos);


        alert("SAVED!");

    }

    $scope.show = function(dlg) {
        if (!$scope.dialogs[dlg]) {
            ons.createDialog(dlg).then(function(dialog) {
                $scope.dialogs[dlg] = dialog;
                if(dlg === 'save-combo.html'){
                    $("#combo1").val($("#d1").val());
                    $($("#d2").val().split(', ')).each(function(i, v){
                        $("#combo2").append($("<option>", { value: v, html: v }));
                    });
                    $("#combo3").val($("#d3").val());
                }
                dialog.show();
            });
        } else {
            $scope.dialogs[dlg].show();
        }
    }

});
```

As you can see I am using jQuery to get the values of the inputs. If this is the problem, is there a better way to do it?

This is the code on the button in the dialog that I use to close the dialog and execute the save function: `<ons-button class="button button--large" ng-click="dialog.hide(); saveCombo('save-combo.html')">SAVE COMBO</ons-button>`

Thank you.

Comment: can you try re-setting required dialog's  form fields like : `$("#comboName").val("");$("#combo1").val("")` just after your `alert("SAVED!");`. By this way they will be blank before opening it again

Comment: I tried that and now when I go to re-open the dialog, instead of the form already having the old data, it is now blank, as if it isn't getting the current data.

Comment: oh..thats true. So you will have to set the data right before you do `$scope.dialogs[dlg].show();`

Comment: That worked. Thanks!